# dropdownlist selection changed - grey out cells

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Hi I'm just new here and I just need some guidance for me to be able to solve the issue that I have. I have a excel file and I have a drop down in column `AA` (Yes or No), I know there's conditional formatting that will change the color of the row. But I have 3000 rows.

What I want to happen is when the user, select on `No`, it will grey out the entire row. Is there easy way. Because it will take some time if i will do it on conditional formatting 1 by 1.

For example, if user on `AA4` select no on drop down. It will gray out `AB4 - AK4`

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with *"It will take some time..."*. Just set a conditional formatting rule for the whole range `AB4:AK4`

Comment: You can use Conditional Formatting, or sheet `Change` event. Even for applying the necessary Conditional Formatting you can use VBA to automate its creation. Please, test the pieces of code I provided in my answer.

Comment: What I mean is if I'm going to do the conditional formatting by row, it will take some time if I will do it one by one. But I have the answers already, and that's really helpful.

Comment: And what I meant is that my code automatically creates all the necessary Conditional Formatting for **all the involved range**... If you choose this variant from the two proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate it in two ways (using VBA):

1. Create cnditional formatting for the necessary range, in this way:

```
Sub makeCondForm()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("AA" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 With sh.Range("AB4:AK" & lastRow)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$AA4=""No"""
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
    End With
 End With
End Sub
```

2. Using Sheet `Change` Event. Please, copy the next code in the sheet code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = Range("AA1").Column Then
        If Target.Value = "No" Then
            With Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), cells(Target.row, "AK")).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
            End With
        Else
            Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), cells(Target.row, "AK")).Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, note that the range in discussion must not have any Conditional Formatting. And it must be initialized, in a way. I mean, it will work only after you change a cell value in the column "AA" from something else to 'No'...

Comment: Thank you so much. I been looking for this VBA code. I will used this. Thank you for your help.. Really appreciate.

Comment: @Jaymie Anne Remz: Did you test it (them)?

Comment: Yup and it's working Thank you so Much FaneDuru, I was looking for this kind of code, thank you for providing it to me. Means a lot.

Comment: But it's weird because on row AA4, when I click no. It also gray out the AB2-AK2 also the AB4 -AK4.

Comment: @Jaymie Anne Remz:  This should not be possible... Did you try both codes, or only the one creating the Conditional Formatting? You maybe tried before some (wrong) manual Conditional Formatting... Please, select the range AB1:AK3 and go Home (tab) - last group (Editing) - Clear - Clear Formats... Please, look into the code. It formats only the necessary range (`"AB4:AK" & lastRow`)...

Comment: @Jaymie Anne Remz: Did you find the problem? If not and not something confidential in the workbook, please share it and I will tell you where the problem is...

Answer (score 1):

You would **NOT** apply this rule row by row. Instead, apply it to one row and then expand the scope of the rule to the desired range. While you can do this in VBA, it is by no means necessary.

---

Use a formula to set your conditional format by navigating to `Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.

Your formula should reference the column of interest (*In my example `Column A` and in yours it's `Column AA`*). Be sure to not lock the row reference and apply your desired format here!

[image]

Once done, navigate to your existing rules to modify the range the rule applies to (`Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > Select newly created rule`). Given my setup, the range to apply the rule is `B2:F10` so the form looks like so:

[image]

---

When done the range supplied in the last step should highlight per the formula and format you applied in the first step

[image]

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the advice and tips, I will try to used this.